# How to show that distance travelled in the $n$'th time interval grows in arithmetic progression

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration, velocity

$\mathbf Q.$ A car starting from rest and accelerating uniformly travels a distance $d$  in the first $n$ seconds and a distance $k$ in the next $n$ seconds. Prove that $ k=3d$

Attempt:
$$d=(v_1)(n)$$
$$k=(v_2)(2n)-\frac{1}{2}(v)(n)$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(v_2)(2n)-\frac{1}{2}(v_1)(n)=3d$$

I don't know what I'm supposed to do. I tried letting $3d=3(\frac{1}{2})(v_1)(n)$, but after that it just went downhill. In the end I got $k=2d-d$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since the car begins from rest and keeps accelerating, the equation $d=vt$ is no longer valid, because velocity is not constant. Note that you can, however, say that $d=v_0 t + {}^1/_2 a t^2 = {}^1/_2 a t^2$ and the acceleration will be the same for both time intervals.

Hope that gives you a nudge in the right direction!

Also, [these equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#Constant_translational_acceleration_in_a_straight_line) may be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the result that the distance, $d$ travelled by a particle with initial speed $u$ with uniform acceleration, $a$ after a time $t$ is $s = ut + \frac{1}{2} a t^2$. Initially you have $u = 0$. For the second part of the question you can calculate $s$ by putting $t=?$

Answer (score -1):

$d = \frac1 2 an^2$ for first n seconds. $(u=0)$

$d+k = \frac1 2 a(2n)^2$  for n+n seconds. $(u=0)$

$d + k   = \frac1 2an^2.4$ = d.4

$=> k = 3d$